How i can insert data in ckeditor textarea
I am trying to edit a textarea which is ckeditor but I am facing an issue if someone knows please tell me.
<div class="col-md-12">
  <a class="btn btn-primary pull-right" id="nextdiv">
    <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
  </a>
  {!! Form::label('content', __('lang_v1.content') . ':*') !!}
  <div id="editor-container">
    <div class="printableArea ck-editor__editable_inline">
      {!! Form::textarea('content[]', null, [
          'class' => 'form-control editor updateEditor',
          'placeholder' => __('lang_v1.content'),
          'id' => 'editor',
      ]) !!}
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="container"></div>
</div>

$(".template").on('change', function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: '/get/template/data/' + templateId,
    type: 'GET',
    success: function(response) {
      console.log(response.content)
      CKEDITOR.instances['editor'].setData(response.content);
    }
  )}
}

It gives this error
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'editor')
What I am doing wrong?

Your code is attempting to read CKEDITOR.instances['editor'], but can't because CKEDITOR.instances is not defined. I'm not familiar with ckeditor, but check the documentation and make sure it's initialized correctly.

According to the official documentation, after you create your editor, you can refer to it using the window.
.then( editor => {
    window.editor = editor;
})

Here is the official documentation.
How to from the official documentation.

thank bro it works
